# Java Programming - Beginner for Paper Rocks Scissors

Tags: java

Need Some Guidance if possible please. New to Java. Not to sure why code below for rocks, papers , scissors game is not working. Any suggestions please or advice would be most welcome. I know there are plenty of examples on this great forum - but i am still grasping the basics. Thank you.

```
import java.util.*;         
import java.util.Scanner;   
import java.util.Random;     
public class Game       
{                           
    public static void main (String[] args){     

        int NumberofRoundsPlayed;        
        int NumberofRoundsWonbyHuman = 0;   

        Scanner Keyboard = new Scanner (System.in       

        System.out.println("DO YOU WANT TO PLAY ROCK PAPER SCISSORS- Y/N");                       
        String HumanPlaying  = Keyboard.nextLine();


        if(HumanPlaying ==("No"))
        {
            System.out.println("Game Over");
            System.exit(0);}
        }       

    int Paper = 1;  
    int Scissor = 2;    
    int Rock  = 3;      

    int HumanSelection;
    int humanroundsWon =0;

    System.out.println("HOW MANY ROUNDS DO YOU WANT TO PLAY");
    NumberofRoundsPlayed = Keyboard.nextInt();      

    while  (NumberofRoundsPlayed <= NumberofRoundsPlayed +1)  
    {
        Scanner Computer = new Scanner (System.in);
        Random rand = new Random();

        int ComputerChoice =Computer.nextInt(3)+1; 
        System.out.println(ComputerChoice);

      System.out.println("Select 1 for Paper, 2 for Scissor or 3 for Rock");                    
        HumanSelection = Keyboard.nextInt();

        //SEE WHO WINS

        If (ComputerChoice== 1)
        {
            If (HumanSelection==1)
            {
            System.out.println("Computer and Human Have Tied");
            }   Else if (HumanSelection==2)
            {
                System.out.println("Person Wins");
                humanroundsWon == humanroundsWon+1;
            }
            Else if (HumanSelection==3)
            {
                System.out.println("Computer Wins");
            }

        Else if (ComputerChoice==2)
        {
            If (HumanSelection==1)
            {
                System.out.println("computer Wins");

            }
            Else if (HumanSelection==2)
            {
            System.out.println("Computer and Person Have Tied");
            }
            Else if (HumanSelection==3)
            {
                System.out.println("Person Wins");
                humanroundsWon == humanroundsWon+1;

            }
        }

        Else if (ComputerChoice==3)
        {

    }
            If (HumanSelection==1)
            {
                System.out.println("Person Wins");
                humanroundsWon == humanroundsWon+1;
            }

        Else if (HumanSelection==2)
        {
            {       System.out.println("Computer Wins");
            }

            Else if (HumanSelection==)
            {
                    System.out.println("Tie");  
                    roundsWon == roundsone+1;
            }
        }
        }
    }
    }
 }

        System.out.println("Game Over");
            System.exit(0);}
```

Comment: In what way is it not working?

Comment: `humanroundsWon == humanroundsWon+1;` should probably be `humanroundsWon = humanroundsWon+1;`. Or `humanroundsWon += 1;`. Or `humanroundsWon++;`.

Comment: thanks elhefe.  i get plenty of syntax errors mainly when the main part of the program starts - ie, after computer selects random number along with the 'human' - it says:   Multiple markers at this line
 - Syntax error on token ""HOW MANY ROUNDS DO YOU WANT TO PLAY"", delete 
  this token
 - Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)
 - Syntax error on token ";", { expected after this token  .     I am having trouble of course understanding the basics at this stage - so i am not too sure what to make of this error code.

Comment: `if` and `else` should not be capitalized.

Comment: you have multiple errors in your program ..

Comment: Properly indenting your code will help you find errors such as missing/extra/misplaced brackets.

Comment: you might already know, but using a IDE will help you a lot (for example, contextual code compilation and errors highlighting). Installation is generally straightforward - for Eclipse there is even no installation; just unpack a zip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the code, if my understanding of your scenario is correct. When you ask  questions, indicate what the `code` actually need to perform, so that others can help you. And a little tip, try to use an IDE like `eclipse` which will help you in coding. you can find it [here](http://Try%20to%20use%20an%20IDE%20like%20%60eclipse%60%20which%20will%20help%20you) just download `Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers` according to your platform architecture( `32bit` or `64bit`) and extract the `zip` file. Then run the `eclipse IDE` it is simple as that

```
import java.util.*;         
import java.util.Scanner;   
import java.util.Random;     
public class Game       
{                           
    public static void main (String[] args){     

        int NumberofRoundsPlayed;        
        int NumberofRoundsWonbyHuman = 0;   

        Scanner Keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);      

        System.out.println("DO YOU WANT TO PLAY ROCK PAPER SCISSORS- Y/N");                       
        String HumanPlaying  = Keyboard.nextLine();


        if(HumanPlaying.equals("No"))
        {
            System.out.println("Game Over");
            System.exit(0);
        }



        int Paper = 1;  
        int Scissor = 2;    
        int Rock  = 3;      

        int HumanSelection;
        int humanroundsWon =0;

        System.out.println("HOW MANY ROUNDS DO YOU WANT TO PLAY");
        NumberofRoundsPlayed = Keyboard.nextInt();      

        while  (NumberofRoundsPlayed < NumberofRoundsPlayed++)  
        {
            Scanner Computer = new Scanner (System.in);
            Random rand = new Random();

            int ComputerChoice =Computer.nextInt()+1; 
            System.out.println(ComputerChoice);

            System.out.println("Select 1 for Paper, 2 for Scissor or 3 for Rock");                    
            HumanSelection = Keyboard.nextInt();

            //SEE WHO WINS

            if (ComputerChoice== 1)
            {
                if (HumanSelection==1)
                {
                    System.out.println("Computer and Human Have Tied");
                }
                else if (HumanSelection==2)
                {
                    System.out.println("Person Wins");
                    humanroundsWon++;
                }
                else if (HumanSelection==3)
                {
                    System.out.println("Computer Wins");
                }
            }
                else if (ComputerChoice==2)
                {
                    if (HumanSelection==1)
                    {
                        System.out.println("computer Wins");

                    }
                    else if (HumanSelection==2)
                    {
                        System.out.println("Computer and Person Have Tied");
                    }
                    else if (HumanSelection==3)
                    {
                        System.out.println("Person Wins");
                        humanroundsWon++;

                    }
                }

                else if (ComputerChoice==3)
                {


                    if (HumanSelection==1)
                    {
                        System.out.println("Person Wins");
                        humanroundsWon++;
                    }

                    else if (HumanSelection==2)
                    {
                        System.out.println("Computer Wins");
                    }

                    else if (HumanSelection==3)
                    {
                        System.out.println("Tie");  

                    }
                }

            }

        System.out.println("Game Over");
        System.exit(0);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi Kasun. Thank you help for all your help. Much appreciated.  And you are spot on - next time i will endeavor to explain what the code needs to do.   Thanks againg, Chris

Comment: Your welcome.  Since my answer solved your problem, you can contribute to this `website` by accepting my answer as the correct one, by clicking the `correct symbol` next to my answer, so that any one with same problem( your problem) will find my answer useful.

Answer (score 1):

If it won't compile, `Scanner Keyboard = new Scanner (System.in` is an incomplete statement.

Comment: Thank you jpfromit.    Chris